# How do I get the printer name to include in `lpoptions -d`

Tags: linux, command-line, printer

I am trying to set the default printer on a machine running xubuntu from the command line.  It looks like I need: `lpoptions -d "printer_name"` but I do not know the name of the printer.  How can I find this information?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command:

```
lpstat -a
```

This returns a list of installed printers.

Comment: thanks for the info but the printer is not currently installed.  It looks like what I was looking for was `lpinfo -v`.

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like `lpstat -p` or `lpstat -a`.  Some information you might only be able to get by visiting `http://localhost:631/printers`, though; I don't see a way to get the location or description from the command line offhand.

Comment: The printer wasn't installed yet.  I prob. should have made that more clear in the question.  Thanks for the info though. I think `lpinfo -v` is what I was looking for.

Comment: If it's not installed yet, it probably doesn't have a name and you can't do much with it then.

Comment: yeah it looks like I was biting off a bit more than I thought when I asked the question.  Since @Christi and you essentially answered the question I asked (and not the one in my head) I am accepting the answer from @Christi since I think she was first.  Thanks.